# Routind with Angular 8 and Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I want to achive routing in angular 8 project. My situation is: I am working on angular and webpack project. I've just updated angular to version 8. i want to add routing functionality to application.

Works:

1. Angular routing works with "RouterLinks". So it works when I am pressing menu button (for both lazy loading and component).
2. Routing works with Hashes (But need to use it without them)

Doesn't work:

1. Routing does not work when I am trying to load page from browser URL typing - for example when I am typing "http://localhost:8080/help", error is: "Cannot GET /help"

What could be the problem? I can copy and paste code if it is needed but before that could you tell me where to start? in webpack configuration? or on different place? Thanks

Router Module :

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: FirstComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    {
        path: 'help',
        loadChildren: () => import('./helpPage/helpPage.module').then(mod => mod.HelpPageModule),
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules}, ),
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Main Module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        FormsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        HelpPageModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ]
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})

export class MainModule { }
```

Help Page Module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HelpPageComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{path: '', component: HelpPageComponent}]),
  ]
})
export class HelpPageModule { }
```

Also, I want to mention that angular is rendering on server side (SSR)

Comment: and how the code looks like?

Comment: Question is too vague. You need to post your code at least as a starter if you expect help.

Comment: Yes I understand but which part are you interested for? I will include edit question and please then tell me if some you need some more for understanding question. Thanks in addition

Comment: I have updated code now can you see something wrong? I think that when routing works with RouterLink and does not work with browser refreshing and app is configured with webpack, is telling much more than this example codes.

Comment: @RobinWebb now it's better? :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't need to change anything in webpack config, if you want to use hash just add `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // .../#/crisis-center/` in `AppModule`

and all pages will use hash

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // .../#/crisis-center/
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  providers: [

  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Yes I know, please see second item which I include inside "Works" - "Routing works with Hashes (But need to use it without them)". Thanks

Comment: Try to reset all changes what you've made to webpack or delete `node_modules` ant then `npm install` maybe something is broken with compiler or webpack and this is why you can't use routes without hash

Comment: Also you can try `ng update --all=true --force=true` after delete `node_modules` for updating all core library used by Angular to make sure you have latest version of all core libraries

Comment: Yes I tried it but unfortunately it didn't helped. Thanks